# ViewFinder is cutting off detail and image has dark edges

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Here is my CaptureElement in my XAML file

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="PhotoPreview" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Here is my .cs file

```
PhotoPreview.Source = _mediaCapture;
PhotoPreview.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

When my viewfinder starts, it shows about a 16:9 view. There are black bars to the left and right. When I take the image, only what was shown in the viewfinder is correct in the image. Everything in the "black bars" is in the image, but it's almost like the brightness isn't captured. The only things that show up are white and they show up a dark green color. I don't know how to upload images, so I'm not sure how to attach it to this question.

`var imageProperties = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
var fileLoc = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, fileLoc);
this.Frame.GoBack();`

Comment: Can you take picture with the normal camera app and do they look fine?

Comment: When using the normal camera app, pictures look as they should, and there are no black bars on the sides of the viewfinder.

Comment: Try setting the HorizontalAlignment of the CaptureElement to Stretch.

Comment: It defaults to stretch, but I declared it stretch anyway just to see, and the problem still persists.

Comment: [Do you have a CommandBar set on the page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7a67bc8-93d1-44a8-afea-3d3b99ce1447/how-to-make-a-captureelement-fill-the-whole-screen-in-a-universal-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)?

Comment: Do you mean the bar at the bottom? The one with Back/Windows/Search buttons? If so, yes it's there. I don't think I can remove it.

Comment: Not the physical buttons. The little black bar that has an ellipsis (`...`) and that you can add little buttons in circles to.

Comment: Oh, in that case no I don't. I just want to make it known that the phone I'm using for development does not have physical buttons, but software buttons. I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, according to the link at the bottom, software buttons seem to have the same effect. Is it a Lumia 630? That's the one that the poster mentions in the link. Apparently holding the phone in portrait in the camera app should have the bars as well. Just to be sure, would you mind adding in some more of your code for capturing the image to make sure you're doing that right. Also initializing the MediaCapture instance.

Comment: I added the code for taking the image

Comment: Is it happening in both portrait and landscape? If only portrait, then maybe you need to handle orientation changes? Try checking [this](http://j4ni.com/blog/?p=162) out.

Comment: It happens in both. In landscape, it is still the same sides of the image being cut off, even though landscape does not have black bars on any sides.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the Stretch being UniformToFill is having an issue. Why do you need it to be UniformToFill?

Comment: When it is set to none, it clips off the screen in portrait mode for some reason, when set to fill it fills vertically only and is about 20px wide, and when set to uniform it is filling about 30% of the screen. UniformToFill is the only option that had it filling the area.

Comment: Ah hah! According to [this](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/) you have to set the resolution *after initialization*, otherwise you get exactly the phenomenon you've described. Give that a try.

Comment: That did it! You are a saint. Please put this as an answer so that I can mark it as answered.